# How to see more information from Xcode linker?

Tags: xcode4, linker, compiler-errors

When I try to compile this project I get the following error.

[image]

I would like to find out more about this error. It says to pass -v to see more information.

How can I do that?

And how can I remove this library from the linker?

Also, and this is an aside question, but does this count as a compiler error, or is it just a link error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says, that the linker failed. The previous line is the linker's error message:

ld: library not found for -lPods.

To remove the dependency on the library, go to project’s “Build Settings” tab and remove -lPods from the key named “Other Linker Flags”. Or, if it's not there, open the “Build Phases” tab and look for it in the list named “Link Binary With Libraries”.

It’s a linker, not compiler error.

Comment: I know. My question is how to get more information from Xcode on that error.

Comment: What do you mean by more information? The linker invocation command? There should be a button at the right in the log (5 horizontal lines), click on it and you will see the command. To remove the dependency on the library, go to project’s “Build Settings” tab and remove -lPods from the key named “Other Linker Flags”. Or, if it's not there, open the “Build Phases” tab and look for it in the list named “Link Binary With Libraries”

Comment: It says to call the linker with the -v option. How can I do that?

Comment: Add `-v` to “Other linker flags”. It will have the same effect as the button I mentioned.

Comment: I mean, you won't be able to see the output until you click the button. You will just get the invocation twice now.

Comment: Where can "other linker flags" be set?

Answer (score 3):

To make your user experience more intuitive, Apple likes to make buttons invisible.

[image]

You can click on lines in the build log to make these buttons visible...

[image]

To make this interface even more obtuse er... I mean, more intuitive, some lines in the build log have these buttons already showing without needing to be clicked first.